# Adding new column to table

Tags: tables

Given the following table, I would like to add a further column:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|}
\hline

Total number of atoms & 426 \\
Number of electrons & 260 \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{test }
\label{t:stats}
\end{table}
```

I assumed it would be something like:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|}
\hline

Total number of atoms & 426 & 520 \\
Number of electrons & 260 & 118 \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{test }
\label{t:stats}
\end{table}
```

..but this does not work. Thanks

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|l|}`. But why the X column? Just to make reading difficult?

Comment: Did not know that it makes reading more difficult - how so?

Comment: It moves the data far from their description. So, unless typesetting in double column, I'd not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because most `tabular`-and-friends require you to update the column specification as well:

```
\begin{tabular}{<col spec>}
  % <your table here>
\end{tabular}
```

or

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}{<col spec>}
  % <your table here>
\end{tabularx}
```

So, for adding another column to the right within your [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) from

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}{ | X | l | }
  % <your table here>
\end{tabularx}
```

you would need (say)

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}{ | X | l | r | }
  % <your table here>
\end{tabularx}
```

Here `r`/`l`/`c`/`p{<len>}` denotes a `r`ight/`l`eft/`c`entre-aligned column, while `p{<len>}` fits a paragraph of width `<len>`. Other options are also available, depending on the packages you're loading.

Comment: Many thanks, quick question: In this setting, how can I add a line below the first row (e.g. to have there the titles)?

Comment: @Pegah: First, using `tabularx` puts the table as wide as `<width>`. If your row-wise content falls far short of `<width>`, it's better to just use a regular `tabular` (without a `<width>` specification). Second, [here is how I'd post your table](https://pastebin.com/ew7j27KY), using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and without [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).